# Detect if Cursor is at the Start of a New Line

Tags: android, newline, android-edittext

Is there a way to detect if the cursor is on a new line in an `EditText`? I have a button that inserts numbers but it can only do it if the cursor is on a new line.

e.g.

1. If the user has not typed anything at all and the button is pressed, a number will be inserted
2. If the user is in the middle of a line and the button is pressed, it will automatically go to the next line and then enter a number.
3. If the user has any amount of lines above the cursor, but the cursor is at the start of a new line and the button is pressed, a number will be inserted.

I can't test if `.getSelectionStart() == 0` on my `EditText`, because that will not help for the second or third case.

Thank you!

EDIT: I know I asked a similar question already, but the answer I got from that did not help, so I decided to ask a more specific and thus completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search through the string for "\n". That should be the new line character.

If the last character is \n, you're on a new line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doh! I should have thought of that. Thanks!